# Show that there can only be finitely many numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $f(1/n) = 1/(n + 1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} → \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. Show that there can only be finitely many numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $$f(1/n) = 1/(n + 1).$$
For this problem I was thinking about using the function $f(z)= z/(z + 1)$, since this function indeed satisfies $f(1/n) = 1/(n + 1)$. But I still failed to prove that there are finite many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which this holds.

Comment: Your function is not analytic (at $z=-1$).  Still, if we had a candidate $g(z)$ it would share infinitely many values with your $f(z)$ on the closed disk of radius $\frac 12$.  Hence $f(z)-g(z)$ would be identically zero on that disk.

Comment: Ohke so is there maybe another way to use the function $ z\rightarrow \frac{z}{z+1}$ ?

Comment: I did use your function!  Take any  disk about $0$ which does not contain $z=-1$.  Then any candidate function would have to coincide with your function on that disk (as the difference would have infinitely many zeroes accumulating at $0$).  But then our candidate would have to be singular at $z=-1$ just as yours is.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how I can use this information for the proof.

Comment: Your function failed as a counter example because it was not analytic (just fails at one point, but still).  If I proposed an alternate candidate, it would have to fail for the same reason!  Specifically, it would have to coincide with your function for $z=-1+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.  Therefore, it too would blow up at $z=-1$.

Comment: Or this one: [Can a holomorphic function satisfy f(1/n)=1/(n+1)?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311099/can-a-holomorphic-function-satisfy-f1-n-1-n1).